# Chaining constructors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, qtscript, constructor-chaining

I'm trying to implement some kind of class hierarchy in JavaScript. I
think I understood the prototype chain, but I still have to sort out the
constructor-chaining. Following David Flanagan's [Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992),
I wrote

```
function DerivedClass()
{
    BaseClass.apply(this, arguments);  // chain constructors
    // do some initializations specific to DerivedClass...
}

var foo = new DerivedClass();
```

where `BaseClass()` is a native function of mine written in C++ (I'm
using [QtScript](http://doc.trolltech.com/scripting.html)). My problem is that then, `BaseClass()` is called
as a function, not as a constructor.

I could code `BaseClass()` to always behave as a constructor, however it
is called. But I am afraid some day one of my users might forget `new`
and just write

```
var bar = BaseClass();
```

In such a situation, I would like `BaseClass()` to do something more
sensible than initializing the global object. For example:

```
if (!context->isCalledAsConstructor()) fail_gracefully();
```

But then the constructor chaining fails!

Is there a way I can chain the constructors and have `BaseClass()`
actually be called as a constructor? Or should I just educate my users
to never forget `new`? Right now I'm tempted to replace the test above
by:

```
if (context->thisObject().strictlyEquals(engine->globalObject()))
    fail_gracefully();
```

but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to handle this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself...

I thought about my problem overnight... and I think I found a somewhat
more satisfying solution: behave as a constructor if `this` is an
instance of the calle. This test is somewhat stricter than checking
whether it's not the global object, but it still allows constructor
chaining, as long as the prototypes have been properly chained.

Here are the first lines of my native constructor (`SerialPort` is my
base class, built around [QSerialDevice](http://gitorious.org/qserialdevice)):

```
/*
 * Should we behave as a constructor?
 *
 * We could use context->isCalledAsConstructor() to decide. However,
 * we may want to subclass SerialPort in JavaScript and chain the
 * constructors:
 *
 *      function DerivedClass()
 *      {
 *          SerialPort.apply(this, arguments);
 *          // do some more initializations...
 *      }
 *
 * This would fail if we decided on the basis of
 * context->isCalledAsConstructor(). The test below is somewhat less
 * strict. It allows constructor chaining provided the prototypes
 * have been properly chained.
 */
bool behave_as_constructor =
    context->thisObject().instanceOf(context->callee());
```

The funny thing about this is: unlike `isCalledAsConstructor()`, this
test can also be implemented in a JavaScript constuctor!

Answer (score 0):

You should educate your users to never forget `new`.

All "constructors" in JavaScript are just functions after all, so you can't protect against a constructor being called as a function.

It's incorrect JavaScript to try and create a new object without using `new`. Just because there isn't a "compile time warning" as there is in Java, doesn't make it any different.

Comment: Well, technically I can protect them by either throwing an exception, or ignoring `this` and returning a brand new object (like `Array()` does). My problem is that the first option interferes with constructor chaining while the second does not play nice with prototype chaining.